# Image over Image convolution in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Assume, I have two set of images, A and B, each 11X5x5x3, where 11 is a number of examples and 5x5x3 is an image dimension.
Is there an easy way in Tensorflow to apply convolution for each image in A_i over B_i (i.e. B_i plays a filter role and A_i is an input in tf.conv2d)? For example, conv2d(A_1,B_1), conv2d(A_2,B_2),...,conv2d(A_11,B_11)
No weight learning here just wanted to apply convolution on one image over another. 
I tried to do it as follow:

```
# change B to 5x5x3x11 to be compatible with tf convolution.
tf.nn.conv2d(A, B, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding ='SAME' )
```

but the problem with this is that it applies convolution on every A_i over all B_i's. I don't want this, I want A_i only over B_j where i==j. Of course I can do it one by one, but it wouldn't be efficient and I need to do it in a batch mode.

Any comment how to solve this problem?

Thanks.
J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure that is what you need because it is not really batch mode but you could use a map function :

```
A = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 5, 5, 3])
B = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 5, 5, 3])

output = tf.map_fn(
    lambda inputs : tf.nn.conv2d(
        tf.expand_dims(inputs[0], 0),  # H,W,C -> 1,H,W,C
        tf.expand_dims(inputs[1], 3),  # H,W,C -> H,W,C,1
        strides=[1,1,1,1],
        padding="SAME"
    ),  # Result of conv is 1,H,W,1
   elems=[A,B],
   dtype=tf.float32
)
final_output = output[:, 0, :, :, 0]  # B,1,H,W,1 -> B,H,W
```

Performance will depend on how the tiny separate convolutions will be parallelized I guess.

Comment: tnx for your time and answer.