# Batched Cross Correlation in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, convolution

I need to perform 2D cross convolution (e.g. like MATLAB's https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr2.html) across a batch of pairs of feature maps.

For clarification:

Let `X` be `B x W1 x H1 x C` and `Y` be `B x W2 x H2 x C`.

The output I want is of shape `B x W2 x H2 x 1` (assuming we treat `X` as the "filter" we pass over `Y` with SAME padding) where the `i`-th `1 x W2 x H2 x 1` slice of the output is the cross correlation between the `X[i,:,:,:]` and `Y[i,:,:,:]` e.g. something like

```
tf.nn.conv2d(Y[i,:,:,:], X[i,:,:,:], [1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
```

**Is there an efficient way to implement this operation?**

Note: if `X` is `1 x W1 x H1 x C` and we want to cross-correlate it with `Y` at each slice `B`, this is easy:

```
cross_corr = tf.nn.conv2d(
    Y, tf.transpose(X, perm[1,2,3,0], [1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
```

which takes advantage of the fact that Tensorflow implements `conv2d` as cross correlation and the fact that the we can treat the smaller tensor as essentially a filter after transposing. This does NOT solve my issue because I need to take the cross convolution of `B` different filters.

Maybe conv3d is a possibility?

Note2: matconvnet's [`vl_nnconv`](http://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/mfiles/vl_nnconv/) does this if the filter channels divides the input channels. Does Tensorflow have an equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `tf.map` function like I showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41766555/2911687).

I tried back then to use `conv3d` but didn't find a way to make it work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is what I'm looking for. Just one comment (I don't have enough rep to comment on the original answer), when you call: `tf.expand_dims(inputs[0], 0)`, doesn't that add an extra dimension? Wouldn't that make the input to tf.nn.conv2d a 5D tensor (does it allow this?)?

Also: by any chance, have you tried running this? Is the map function actually parallelized on GPU?

Comment: I tried running, it works. About speed, honestly no idea.
Basically map(4D,4D) apply a function on each (3D,3D) slice, so basically a 'per-image' function. The two `tf.expand_dims` are converting the (3D,3D) to a (4D,4D) that get convolved with each others.
The final result is a 5D tensor but with two dimensions equal to 1 so we get rid of them at the end.  (I have commented my original answer for clarification)

Answer (score 1):

[TensorFlow 2.x version]

I am not sure if this method was around at the time this question was asked, but you can try `tf.nn.convolution`:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/convolution

It looks like the method supports multiple filters, and deals with N-D convolutions, where N must be 1, 2, or 3.